# How to use PollTimeout in NetMQ?

Tags: c, zeromq, netmq

I can't find any documentation telling me how to use PollTimeout in NetMQ.
Can it be used to detect a send or receive timeout? In case it can, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can TrySendFrame and TryReceiveFrame which accept TimeSpan as timeout.

However the stable release in nuget doesn't include them. So compile from master or use the latest pre version:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/NetMQ/3.3.0.13-alpha622

Comment: Thank you. I've seen those methods, but I'm still curious what PollTimeout is and what I can use it for.

Comment: PollTimeout is for cancelling the poller, when polling you wait for one of the socket to become ready, the PollTimeout is for the polling to check if the polling is cancelled. So If you PollTimeout of 1 second it can take up to 1 second to cancel the poller.